# what is the meaning of ii=(char*)&i and a=(char*)&a in the following code

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    float a = 3.14;
    char*ii,*aa;

    ii = (char*)&i;
    aa = (char*)&a;
    printf("address contained in ii=%u\n",ii);
    printf("address contained in aa=%u\n",aa);
    printf("value at address contained in ii=%d\n",*ii);
    printf("value at address contained in aa= %d\n",*aa);
    return(0);
} 
/*the output for the following program was 
  address contained in ii=65524

 address contained in aa=65520
  value at address contained in ii=5

  value at address contained in aa=-61*/
```

What is the meaning of `ii = (char*) &i` and `aa = (char*) &a` also why does the compiler print value at address in `ii` to be correct and that in `aa` to be wrong? If you take any other value of `i`, say 327, then the value at address contained in `ii` will turn out to be something else. Can someone please explain it to me? I am not able to get a proper explanation from the book where the code is written.

Program source: understanding pointers in c.  Author : yashvant kanetkar,4th edition.

Comment: That program has issues, it's probably very old. To print the address of a pointer you need to cast to `void *` and use the `"%p"` `printf()` specifier. The program is also incorrect, the author is dereferencing the pointer through an aliased pointer which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: The program shouldn't compile. How did you get *output*?

Comment: @BlueMoon I didn't see the `float a = 3,14`.

Comment: @iharob I didn't see that either :) Also there are multiple  `i` and `a` variables.

Comment: @BlueMoon Oh ... I missed that too and also, none of the pointers is initialized, this program is all undefined behavior if it were to ever compile. I think the OP meant `char **ii, **aa;` and since the Ctrl+A Ctrl+C Ctrl+V is so difficult and takes so much time, they preferred to type the whole program again.

Comment: Ditch the Kanetkar book - seriously - all his books are terrible - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for a list of much better books to learn C from.

Comment: @PaulR There are a lot of terrible books, I think it's because good programmers do programming and teachers are so because they were not as good writing programs. Except for very few cases like Knuth and Stroustrup.

Comment: Yes, it's rare to find someone who is both a good programmer and a good teacher/writer, but there are a few out there. Kanetkar though is one of the worst examples - his books are full of misinformation, bad code, undefined behaviour, etc, and they are seriously out-of-date. Unfortunately his books seem to be standard in Indian colleges, so every year we get a new crop of novice programmers who badly need to unlearn a lot of what they think they know about C/C++.

Comment: @rookie: you've edited the code now but it still doesn't even compile - please only post your *actual code* (hint: use copy and paste).

Comment: Sorry, but this is really from a published book?

Comment: I also invite @haccks  sir to read the question. [Note: see the book name] :-)

Comment: @brauner sadly, yes....

Comment: Why is the first pointer printed with `%u` and the second with `%d`? Both are wrong, but in any case: why the difference?

Comment: I see that the OP has now edited the program to be very much closer to the text from the source document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program as given in the book is an example of what not to do:

Don't try to access a value through a pointer when the pointer is not a pointer to the same type as the original value.

In the book, `i` is an `int`, but the code deliberately makes a `char*` point to the integer. So, when `ii` is dereferenced you just get a value that seems to be a `char`.

**edit:** So, the expression `(char*)&i;` first takes the address of `i`, which the compiler thinks of as type `int*` and then converts the type to `char*` without changing the value of the pointer.

The important thing to note about the different types of pointers is that they often imply a different size of object pointed to.

Also note that the output of all the whole program will depend on the platform you are using.

Comment: agreed..... but what does the statement (char*)&i do ? does it make ii think that the address stored in it is that of a character ??